# Gerrit: how to rebase on remote changed commit under review?

Tags: git, gerrit

I think i have a sort of understanding problem.

For example: I have three commits which looks like the following on the remote repository:

```
Commit A: Already merged
Commit B: Under review, rebased over the webinterface from an other user, based on commit A
Commit C: Under review, based on commit B
```

My local repository looks like this:

```
Commit A: Already merged
Commit B: Under review, based on commit A
Commit C: Under review, based on commit B
```

So now the problem is, i do not know how i can get the new, rebased, version of commit B. If i try git pull or git fetch it git tells me, there is nothing to update, but if i try to upload a new version of B, I get an error because of the differences beteween my local B and the remote B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing probably is to look at commit B in the Gerrit web UI, and then (provided that you are using the "Change Screen 2" layout) look at the upper right corner for the "Download" drop-down menu, and click on the copy-to-clipboard icon next to "Checkout". If you paste this to the command line, Git will checkout out commit B in "detached HEAD" mode. Note that this will not give you commit C, but I guess that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, i think i understand. But how do i replace my commit B with this detached HEAD commit B? For example: commit B changes `foo/bar/test.txt` im in the `foo` folder and i checkout B like you said. Is my local B commit automaticaly replaced? Or do i have to "tell" git that it should use the new B? If yes, how?

Comment: Your local commit B is not automatically replaced. After checking out the detached HEAD based on Gerrit's B you're basically working on an alternate history compared to yours. But what is is that you're trying to achieve? Do you just want to continue working by creating a commit D on top of Gerrit's B and C?

Comment: Yes, thats the basic problem. Because if a B is remote changed, i can not push my local comments anymore.. so i have to replace my local B to the remote changed B to push C and other new commits. I think this is exactly the problem i want to solve https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2936

Comment: The issue you're linking mentions a few details that you were so far unclear about: On Gerrit, did the other user also rebase C onto the new B from the web interface? Did you do a `git pull --rebase` locally? Are you locally working with branches instead of detached HEAD states? If all of this is true, the easiest solution probably is to just reset your local branch to the new C from Gerrit and continue working. If your working tree is clean, you can do this by downloading the change as per my answer, switching back to your branch with `git checkout -`, and `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`.